# Run a loop off of a grouping of data in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large file of vendor records that I am looking for duplicates in. Duplicate values may appear in either the vendor name or the vendor address. I am using the dupandas package but need to break my data into smaller chunks in order to not overwhelm my computer's memory. Because possible duplicate records must all have the same state, I am trying to split my vendor dataframe by the state field and then run dupandas on each state. I am having difficulty, however, figuring out how to write the for loop to accomplish the following:
1. take all rows for the first state (e.g. AK)
2. run dupandas on it and write the result into a dataframe
3. move to the next state (e.g. CA) and repeat step 2.

It seems like this should be straight forward but for some reason it is totally stumping me.

Here is the non-loop form that works with my artificially created subset for all vendors in the state of WA:

```
import os
from os import rename,listdir
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_fwf, DataFrame, Series
import csv
from dupandas import Dedupe

#set directory
loc1 = os.chdir('C:/')

#find file and open it
vendor = pd.read_csv('vendor.txt', sep = '\t')

#fix OR originally coded with zeros
vendor.loc[vendor['province'] == '0R', 'province'] = 'OR'
vendor['province'] = vendor['province'].fillna('NA')

#create one field that is a concatenate of the vendor address
vendor['addr'] = vendor['address1']+' '+vendor['city']+' '+vendor['province']+' '+vendor['associate ein']
vendor['subset'] = vendor['province']+' '+vendor['BUSINESS ACTIVITY CODE']

#test dupandas on vendors in the state of WA or CT
WA = vendor.loc[((vendor['province'] == 'WA') | (vendor['province'] == 'CT')) & (vendor['BUSINESS ACTIVITY CODE'].str.contains('VRT'))]

#initialize configurations for dupandas
clean_config = { 'lower' : True, 'punctuation' : True, 'whitespace' : True, 'digit' : False }
match_config = { 'exact' : False, 'levenshtein' : True, 'soundex' : False, 'nysiis' : False}
dupe = Dedupe(clean_config = clean_config, match_config = match_config)

input_config = {
    'input_data' : WA, 
    'column' : 'vndr_nm', 
    '_id' : 'vndr_cd'
    }
```

results = dupe.dedupe(input_config)

Comment: You can just `df.groupby('state').transform(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates())`

Comment: How many columns you have in you real data?

Comment: @coldspeed my duplicates are not identical in most cases and need to be reviewed to be certain they need cleaning up. We are trying to identify which records are actually duplicates based on probabilities.

Comment: @wen I have 9 columns of data.